# Only run trigger if value is FALSE

Tags: sql-server

After some trial and error, along with your help, I have come up with the following code for my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER   [dbo].[SnapChapas] 
ON              [dbo].[Tab_Inventarios_Chapas] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF UPDATE(Ativo)
  DECLARE @IDInventario as INT
  SET @IDInventario = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)

  INSERT 
  INTO          Tab_Inventarios_Chapas_Snap_Banco
  (             ID_Tab_Chapas,
                FormatoL,
                Comprimento1,
                Comprimento2,
                Largura1,
                Largura2,
                Quantidade,
                ID_Tab_Inventarios_Chapas
  )
  SELECT        ID,
                FormatoL,
                Comprimento1,
                Comprimento2,
                Largura1,
                Largura2,
                Quantidade,
                @IDInventario
  FROM          Tab_Chapas
```

The code above is working. My problem here is: I Have a column called `"ACTIVE"` in `[dbo].[Tab_Inventarios_Chapas]`. I need the trigger to *only* run if the updated value is `FALSE`.

P.S.: My Application *only* updates *one* line at a time; there’s no way to update more than one.

Comment: *"can anybody help me with that trigger?"* isn't a question we can answer; it's simply a "yes" or "no" answer, which doesn't actually help you. Instead, show us what you've written so far, and explain what about it isn't working. Give us some sample data (as DDL and DML statements) and expected results, so we can see what you're working towards. Then we explain why your attempt(s) didn't work and get you back on the right path.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu try to post at least a sample from a sample table and trigger if you don't want to post private stuff. Otherwise, help is only possible if someone can work with myreries and wondersome powers and these people usually don't hang around StackOverflow :-(

Comment: Hello Everybody, sorry for the bad way of question... trying to do it better: changed the question

Comment: Use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables for the current/previous versions of the rows involved, and you can use `IF UPDATE(Active)` to test if the column was involved in the update (but not the actual changes; for that you need to join the tables).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you for your help, i'll try to change and come back

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeroenMostert, I could find an answer.

Here is my final code:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SnapChapas] 
       ON  [dbo].[Tab_Inventarios_Chapas] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @ativo as bit
Set @ativo = (select Ativo from inserted)
if UPDATE(Ativo) and @ativo='False'
declare @IDInventario as int
Set @IDInventario = (select ID from inserted)
insert into Tab_Inventarios_Chapas_Snap_Banco (ID_Tab_Chapas,FormatoL,Comprimento1,Comprimento2,Largura1,Largura2,Quantidade,ID_Tab_Inventarios_Chapas)
select ID,FormatoL,Comprimento1,Comprimento2,Largura1,Largura2,Quantidade,@IDInventario
from Tab_Chapas

END
```

Thank You!

Comment: Regardless of whether you expect only one row to be updated at a time, you should never write a trigger this way, because if a DBA or similar does some manual corrections to the database and updates a bunch of rows at once you need your trigger to always carry out the correct action. Or throw an error and rollback the update if more than one row is updated.